# Unconfoundedness with Semi-Deterministic Assignment

Tags: causality

Consider an experimental setting where we observe outcomes, binary treatment, and some covariates $(Y,D,X)$ in Rubin's Potential Outcomes Framework.

If the treatment assignment mechanism is completely random (e.g. flip a coin for each individual), then we may assume unconditional unconfoundedness
$$ Y(1), Y(0) \perp D $$
An alternative way of randomization that is sometimes done to improve covariate balance especially in small samples is to match individuals based on some characteristics $X$, and then randomly assign each group (e.g. a pair) to treatment/control. In this case we may assume conditional unconfoundedness
$$ Y(1), Y(0) \perp D | X $$

---

The situation I am considering is where the treatment $D$ is deterministically assigned to some individuals but random for others. As a simple example, let's suppose we are investigating the effect of a drug $D$ on health outcomes $Y$. We run an experiment on a group of individuals and observe covariates $X \in \{male, female\}$, but then only randomly assign females to treatment/control. The assignment mechanism is then
$$ \mathbb{P}(D=1|X) = \begin{cases} & 0.5 \quad (if X = female) \\ & 0 \quad (if X = male) \end{cases} $$
So that $D$ is deterministic for males but random for females. The ATE for the whole population is unidentified here, but the ATT should be identified. However, are we able to assume conditional unconfoundedness?